# poles and unform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of functions uniformly convergent on $\mathcal S^*=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid0<|z|<1\}$. Denote by $f$ the limit of the sequence $(f_n)_n$. Let $\beta$ be a positive integer. Suppose that for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $0$ is a pole of $f_n$ with order $\beta$. Recall that $0$ is said to be a pole of order $\beta$ of $f_n$ if $\lim_{\substack{z\in\mathcal S^*\\z\to0}}z^\beta f_n(z)=c_n$ with $c_n\in\mathbb C^*$. Is it true that $0$ is a pole of order $\beta$ of $f$? I did not manage to prove it, so I wonder if it is not false....

Comment: Can we assume that each term $f_n$ is analytic everywhere else, besides the pole at $z = 0$?

Comment: Yes, it would be already useful to know.

Comment: I would consider the Laurent series $f_n(z) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty a^n_k z^k$. If we fix any $0 < r < 1$, then $a^n_k = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z| = r} \frac{f_n(z)}{z^{k + 1}}dz$, and the same goes for the limit $f(z) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty a_k z^k$. By uniform convergence, we get $a_k^n \rightarrow a_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. From that, we can at least conclude that $a_{-\beta - 1} = a_{-\beta - 2} = \dots = 0$. Depending on whether $a_{-\beta} = 0$, $f(z)$ has a pole of order $\beta$ or lower. I haven't figured out if it's possible for $a_{-\beta}$ to be $0$.

Comment: If the convergence is uniform, it seems that $a_{-\beta} \neq 0$. For simplicity, I consider the special case of order $1$ pole. We have $f_n(z) = \frac{a^n_{-1}}{z} + g_n(z)$, $f(z) = \frac{a_{-1}}{z} + g(z)$, where $g_n(z), g(z)$ are analytic. Then $g_n(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\zeta| = r} \frac{f_n(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}d\zeta$. Since $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, we get $g_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly in a closed disk $D$ around $0$. Hence, $\frac{a^n_{-1}}{z} \rightarrow \frac{a_{-1}}{z}$ uniformly on $D$. This happens if and only if $a^n_{-1} = a_{-1}$ eventually.